# How can I open a popup window to alarm user and running in background?

Tags: c#, winforms, popup, alarm

I need to alarm user by opening a popup window when it is raining and get him\her a feedback by pressing a button to sure that he\she knows the weather status. But I want the other lines of my code running in background. In other words I am looking for a solution that it does not cause stopping the program until users press button. I use Visual studio 2013 WinForms.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: WinForms? WPF? ASP.NET?

Comment: Dear dymanoid, Visual studio 2013 WinForms

Comment: You can show your Popup window by calling `YourWindow.Show()` rather that `YourWindow.ShowDialog()`. This will display your window as non-modal, and your code will continue execution.

Comment: Dear dymanoid, in your solution, is it possible to get the result of pressing button as MessageBox?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but if you mean whether you can get a `System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult` value on a button click, then - yes. That's no problem. But you have to close your window explicit, as setting `DialogResult` won't do that because your window is non-modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your exact requirements are, however

`Messagebox.show` shows a `messagebkx` that is known as 'modal' meaning that you can't interact with the other windows while it's open. To have a non modal message box, try creating a new form and using `messagebox.show` to display it.
You'll have to create a Form and use `Show()` to display.

Note that with `messagebox.show` you get the result as soon as the `messagebox` is closed, a non-modal message box does not do this and you will need to code something to handle that such as an event.

If not an event, what you may be looking for is `async` `await`.

`Async` and `await` are two C# keywords, more info can be found in Microsoft documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx

If you make an `async` method called `showDialogAsync()` that awaits the users result, and then await it on a new thread you will get the following outcome:

Your program is running as normal
Conditions are met and the dialog needs to be shown
 `showDialogAsync` is called and awaited.
`Showdialogasync` awaits the users input. 
Control is returned to the method that called the `showDialogAsync`
When the user clicks a button, the code after the await on the calling method will run.

This diagram shows control flow in some `async` code and may be helpful:
http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC612215.png

Comment: The question is, as far as I understand, how to show a non-modal pop-up. This has nothing to do with async/await or multithreading.